# tex4ht does not handle multline well in mathjax mode

Tags: tex4ht, multline

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
(6 A t+2 B) e^{it}+i (3At^{2}+2Bt+C) e^{it}+i(3At^{2}+2Bt+C) e^{it}\\
-(  At^{3}+Bt^{2}+Ct) e^{it}+( At^{3}+Bt^{2}+Ct) e^{it}=t^{2}e^{it}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following output in HTML when compiled using `make4ht foo1.tex "mathjax"`, The split equation drifts apart when resizing the window making it look bad on wide monitor or wide browser window.

Is it possible to make the split equation remain intact as the case when compiling math using images?  Does this need some make4ht mathjax additional configuration?

[image]

[image]

Compare the output above to when compiling math with images (svg or png), where the multline equation do not drift apart as the window size changes

[image]

Using TL 2019

Comment: I am afraid that this issue is not related to `tex4ht` at all. MathJax decides about formatting. You can maybe set `max-width` using CSS to prevent too big resizing.

Comment: @michal.h21 Ok, thanks Michal. I did not know that is why I asked. Will delete my question in this case no problem.

Comment: that's OK, I can post answer with the necessary CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendering is done by MathJax. It apparently aligns the first line to the left and the second to the right. When the page has a large viewport and thus too long lines, they can be placed far away. The fix for this is to set maximum line size. Which is a good idea anyway:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{ max-width: 55em;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: One more feather in your hat....